# Why is there a space before the last full stop in the citation?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, citing, cite-package

When I write a citation, the compiled file has a space before the last period.

Example:

> Butt, Miriam. 2012. Modern approaches to case: An
> overview. of Malchukov & Spencer .

Note the space between “Spencer” and the period.

The command is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand\bibstyle@comma{\bibpunct(),a,,}
\newcommand\bibstyle@semicolon{\bibpunct();a,,}

@article{Butt,
  title={Modern Approaches to Case: An Overview},
  author={Butt, Miriam},
  journal={of Malchukov $\&$ Spencer },
  year={2012}
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example. Without knowing the bibliography style it is impossible to say which of the fields is used. I would have expected that you got an error for `$&$` which should be `\&`

Comment: The space is actually part of your journal title, it seems.

Comment: `report` is unrelated, the `\bibliographystyle`  is what matters but please always provide complete examples that may be used to see the isssue and test answers.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{linquiry.bst}

Comment: I enter the data manually,

Answer (score 6):

Never trust Google Scholar for BibTeX data. The article you're citing is *not* in a journal, but in a collection. You find it [here](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199206476.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199206476-e-3)

Here's a better BibTeX entry:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{butt,
  author={Butt, Miriam},
  title={Modern Approaches to Case: An Overview},
  booktitle={The Oxford Handbook of Case},
  editor={Andrej L. Malchukov and Andrew Spencer},
  publisher={Oxford Handbooks Online},
  year={2012},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{butt}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` just for making the code self-contained, insert the data in your `.bib` file.

[image]

Comment: it works, thanks